# karma declaration exception

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I can't seem to get started with karma. While it's trying to load the service it fails. Here's the spec file:

```
describe('Service: angelloModel', function () {

    beforeEach(module('Angello'));

    var modelService;

    beforeEach(inject(function (angelloModel) {
        modelService = angelloModel;
    }));

    describe('#getStatuses', function () {
       it('should return seven different statuses', function () {
          expect(modelService.getStatuses().length).toBe(7);
        });
     })
});
```

The karam config section for files to use:

```
    files: [
                'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
                 app.js',
                 'tests/*.spec.js'
            ],
```

and finally the error:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 34.0.1847 (Mac OS X 10.9.2)]: Connected on socket edWal-wdFxcFp1KPQndO with id 43277901
 Chrome 34.0.1847 (Mac OS X 10.9.2) Service: angelloModel encountered a declaration exception FAILED
    ReferenceError: module is not defined
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/e002678/dev/Dropbox/angular/ng-inaction/tests/angelloModel.spec.js:3:16)
        at /Users/e002678/dev/Dropbox/angular/ng-inaction/tests/angelloModel.spec.js:1:1
Chrome 34.0.1847 (Mac OS X 10.9.2): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.015 secs / 0.013 secs)
```

here's the service definition:

```
myModule.factory('angelloModel', function () {
var getStatuses = function () {
    ...
};

var getTypes = function () {
  ...
};

var getStories = function () {
  ...
};

return {
  getStatuses: getStatuses,
  getTypes: getTypes,
  getStories: getStories
};
```

});

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to include `angular-mocks.js` in your files array, after angular and before your test files.

[Here's an example config](https://github.com/jimschubert/eab/blob/master/config/karma.conf.js#L14) from a template project of mine.